# KVM low network speed

Tags: linux, centos, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I have a networking problem with KVM.

There is only one VM on the server and port speed is 100 megabits per second

But maximum download rate is about 1 megabytes per second and expected to be 10mb.

I use virtio and drivers are installed and loaded into kernel.

I tried other NICs but no change and I use bridge networking on the host.

so how to fix this slow performance?

Comment: Are you using bridged networking or something else? What does `iperf` show?

Comment: Thanks, yes I setup bridge networking with KVM, what exactly do you want from iperf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible, check the link speed on switch. It might be set to 10 Mbit/s (10BASE-T). Try connecting directly to server using cross-over cable. If that also fails, the problem is somewhere in configuration/server performance.